# How to write a script that can automatically respond to a Popup window

Tags: python, google-chrome

I have a website that randomly has popups that need to be responded to. How would I go about writing a script that would run that would automatically respond to the popup ( any answer choice)  in my web browser

Comment: Anymore info ? can we see the website ?
Also what have you tried yet ?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I have never written a browser script before. I mostly write scripts for other file-related tasks. The website is not really accessible to non-students. It acts as a regular popup during the duration of an online lecture as a means of attendance